# starting a process with eval

Tags: python, process, eval

```
   **exe.py**
    def createProcess(f):
        try:
            from multiprocessing import Process
            newProcess = Process(target=f)
            newProcess.start()
            newProcess.join()
        except:
            print "Error creating process"

    def lala():
        print "success creating process"

    print "tying to make a process"
    from multiprocessing import Process
    newProcess = Process(target=lala)
    newProcess.start()

    **main.py**
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        f = open("exe.py", "r")
        b = f.read()
        f.close()
        o = compile(b, "exe.py", "exec")
        eval(o)
```

i get the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Program Files\Opsware\agent\lcpython15\lib\multiprocessing\forking.p
    ", line 374, in main
        self = load(from_parent)
      File "C:\Program Files\Opsware\agent\lcpython15\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in
    load
        return Unpickler(file).load()
      File "C:\Program Files\Opsware\agent\lcpython15\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in
    oad
        dispatch[key](self)
      File "C:\Program Files\Opsware\agent\lcpython15\lib\pickle.py", line 1090, in
    load_global
        klass = self.find_class(module, name)
      File "C:\Program Files\Opsware\agent\lcpython15\lib\pickle.py", line 1126, in
    find_class
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lala'
```

later edit

i changed the exe.py to

```
    def lala2():
        f = open("C:\\work\\asdfas", "w")
        f.write("dsdfg\r\n")
        f.close()
        print "success creating process"

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print "tying to make a process"
        from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support 
        freeze_support()
        import pickle
        l = pickle.dumps(lala2)
        pickle.loads(l)()
        newProcess = Process(target=pickle.loads(l))
        newProcess.daemon = True
        newProcess.start()
        if newProcess.is_alive() == True:
            print "alive"
        else:
            print "not alive"
        import time
        time.sleep(12)
```

this should make it importable and because of the pickle test it shows that my method is pickable. any suggestions on why it behaves this way?

Comment: why not just use subprocess to run the .py file?

Comment: for the moment i am restricted on using eval.

Answer (score 2):

You're on Windows. Unfortunately, on Windows, it is not possible to use a dynamic code object as a target for `multiprocessing` because the Windows implementation of multiprocessing must be able to import the main module (the technical reason is because Windows lacks a native `fork()` equivalent). Please see the [multiprocessing programming guidelines for Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) for more details on the applicable restrictions.

The solution is to write the code to a file, then `import` it to start the server.

Comment: consider that the exe.py is a plugin and that for the moment I have to use eval. this should be working on both unix/windows. How would you do it?

Comment: so adding if __name__ == '__main__': to my exe.py for the process creation does not solve the problem, altough it is importable as a module